# Js code for progressbar, not working

Tags: javascript

```
<div><div id="movingbar"></div></div>

var i;
function startTime( i )
{
    if ( i < 100 )
    {
        document.getElementById("movingbar").style.width = i + "%";
        t = setTimeout('startTime( i++ )', 1000);
    } else return;
}
```

This should produce something like a progress bar. But the function is executed only once. What is wrong O_o The recursion should not end until **i** is under 100!?! No errors on FireBug and IE.

Comment: All good answers, but also you want to do it if i<= 100 otherwise you never completely fill the progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're passing a string to timeout which is the code to be evaluated you're actually telling it to run the code 'startTime(i)' and i is undefined at the time that it's run. What you want it to run is 'startTime(2)', 'startTime(3)', etc.

This should work for you:

```
t = setTimeout('startTime(' + ++i + ')', 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<div style="height: 20px;"><div id="movingbar" style="height: 20px;background: #000;"></div></div>

window.onload=function(){var i=1;
startTime(i);
}

    function startTime( i )
 {
     if ( i < 100 )
     {
         document.getElementById("movingbar").style.width = i + "%";
         i++;
         t = setTimeout('startTime('+i+')', 1000);
     } else return;
 }
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/pHxSy/

Comment: a block-element (like a div) without a specified with and without other stylings always consumes 100% width - so i don't think this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the string literal `i++` to your function. Try using an anonymous function.

```
function startTime( i )
{
    if ( i < 100 )
    {
        document.getElementById("movingbar").style.width = i + "%";
        i++;
        t = setTimeout(function() { startTime(i); }, 1000);
    } else return;
}
```